# Force control on UR5e using moveit

Tags: ros, force, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For my project, an UR5e needs to follow a spline. At the end of the spline is needs to move into a certain direction with a constant force. The spline is succesfully executed using the cartesian path planning in moveit. It is still a bit bumpy, but a least it works. However, I am struggling with the constant force part. As far as I know moveit has no implementation of force control. The ur_rtde library (see forcemode https://sdurobotics.gitlab.io/ur_rtde/examples/examples.html) has a built in function for this, but this means that I cannot use moveit anymore (including the collision detection) since moveit requires external control on the teach pendant. Is there anybody that has experience using moveit and force control on an UR5e robot?

I am using ROS melodic on ubuntu 18.04 with the universal robot ros driver (https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver (kinetic-devel).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361402/force-control-on-ur5e-using-moveit/) by [Bvm](https://answers.ros.org/users/59276/bvm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-09-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> As far as I know moveit has no implementation of force control.

Correct. It is a planning framework which mostly deals with kinematics.

> The `ur_rtde` library (see forcemode https://sdurobotics.gitlab.io/ur_rtde/examples/examples.html) has a built in function for this, but this means that I cannot use moveit anymore (including the collision detection) since moveit requires external control on the teach pendant.

What you could potentially do is use the Dashboard server integration in `Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver` to enable and disable the external control URCap when needed.

If you're not controlling the robot "from ROS", the URCap does not need to be running. So if you want to use something else for a bit, that should be possible, and was actually one of the main design drivers of the new driver: make it possible to control the robot externally, but don't take over control completely, only when it is desirable.

Note that the URCap does not need to be running to receive status information from the robot, only to control it. So technically it would be possible to keep at least collision detection working (but you'd have to put something together yourself, using just the monitoring parts of MoveIt).

Main uncertainty here is whether `Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver` can deal with another RTDE client changing the active recipe/configuration (and vice-versa of course). That would be something to check.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bvm](https://answers.ros.org/users/59276/bvm/) on 2020-09-14**:
Thank you for the quick answer. I did not know about the dashboard server, definitely going to try that this week.

The `Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver` still works with two connections. By keeping external control off I am indeed able to send force commands to the robot using the `ur_rtde` library, while Moveit is running in the background. By combining this with the dashboard server integration I should be able to use both the cartesian path planning of Moveit and the force control of ur_rtde so thanks a lot!

**Comment by [waltergun](https://answers.ros.org/users/93587/waltergun/) on 2022-08-05**:
Did you find any solution using ROS? Thank you.

**Comment by [Bvm](https://answers.ros.org/users/59276/bvm/) on 2022-08-12**:
I was not able to apply advanced forced control in ROS since these features were not available. I tried the abovementioned solution to switch between the external control and the python ur_rtde library, which worked okay, but ofcourse not a real robust solution. In the end, I decided to only use the ROS driver and made some simple force feedback using the `/wrench` topic.

**Comment by [waltergun](https://answers.ros.org/users/93587/waltergun/) on 2022-08-12**:
@Bvm, thank you. What results have you achieved? Did you achieved the stable force when following the spline?

**Comment by [bach](https://answers.ros.org/users/66642/bach/) on 2023-02-09**:
Do you know what is the measurement unit of the data from `/wrench`? I thought N, but I get very high values for small forces.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-02-10**:
As per [REP-103: Standard Units of Measure and Coordinate Conventions](https://ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html#units), `Wrench` uses N and Nm.

That would be the message *definition*. Whether the publisher you receive messages from adheres to this convention would be a different question.